# Visual Studio 2010 Express compatible with Community 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express

Is Visual Studio 2010 Express compatible with Visual Studio Express Community 2015? I want do edit applications made in 2010 version.

Comment: Yes .. it's compatible ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes .. it's compatible .. The application created using Visual Studio 2010 will also open on visual studio 2015 ..